# How to benchmark a crypto library?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, openssl, benchmarking

What are good tests to benchmark a crypto library?

Which unit (time,CPU cycles...) should we use to compare the differents crypto libraries?

Are there any tools, procedures....?

Any Idea, comment is welcome!

Thank you for your inputs!

Comment: It's going to depend on the library & encryption schemes available, and the platform options you have available to you.  For example:  Is it Symmetric key or Asymmetric key encryption you're testing?  Are you testing encryption or just digital signature generation?  Is key strength or raw performance more important to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are good tests to benchmark a crypto library?

The answers below are in the context of Crypto++. I don't now about other libraries, like OpenSSL, Botan, BouncyCastle, etc.

The Crypto++ library has a built-in benchmarking suite.

---

> Which unit (time,CPU cycles...) should we use to compare the differents crypto libraries?

You typically measure performance in cycles-per-byte. Cycles-per-byte depends upon the CPU frequency. Another related metric is throughput measured in MB/s. It also depends upon CPU frequency.

---

> Are there any tools, procedures....?

```
git clone https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp.git
cd cryptopp
make static cryptest.exe

# 2.0 GHz (use KB=1024; not 1000)
make bench CRYPTOPP_CPU_SPEED=1.8626
```

`make bench` will create a file called `benchmark.html`.

If you want to manually run the tests, then:

```
./cryptest.exe b <time in seconds> <cpu speed in GHz>
```

It will output an HTML-like table without `<HEAD>` and `<BODY>` tags. You will still be able to view it in a web browser.

You can also check the Crypto++ benchmark page at [Crypto++ Benchmarks](http://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks.html). The information is dated, and its on our TODO list.

---

You also need accumen for what looks right. For example, SSE4.2 and ARMv8 have a CRC32 instruction. Cycles-per-byte should go from about 3 or 5 cpb (software only) to about 1 or 1.5 cpb (hardware acceleration). It should equate to a change of roughly 300 or 500 MB/s (software only) to roughly 1.5 GB/s (hardware acceleration) on modern hardware running around 2 GHz.

Other technologies, like SSE2 and NEON, are trickier to work with. There's a theoretical cycles-per-byte and throughput you should see, but you may not know what it is. You may need to contact the authors of the algorithm to find out. For example, we contacted the authors of BLAKE2 to learn if our ARMv7/ARMv8 NEON implementation was performing as expected because it was [missing benchmark results](http://blake2.net/) on the author's homepage.

I've also found GCC 4.6 (and above) and `-O3` can make a big difference in software-only implementations. That's because GCC heavily vectorizes at `-O3`, and you might witness a 2x to 2.5x speedup.For example, the compiler may generate code that runs at 40 cpb at `-O2`. At `-O3` it may run at 15 or 19 cpb. A good SSE2 or NEON implementation should outperform the software-only implementation by at least a few cycles per byte. In the same example, the SSE2 or NEON implementation may run at 8 to 13 cpb.

There's also sites like [OpenBenchmarking.org](https://openbenchmarking.org/) that may be able to provide some metrics for you.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean performance benchmarks.  I would say that both time and cycles are valid benchmarks, as some code may execute differently on different architectures (perhaps wildly differently if they're different enough).

If it is extremely important to you, I would do the testing myself.  You can use some timer (almost all languages have one) or you can use some profiler (almost all languages have one of these too) to figure out the exact performance for the algorithms you are looking for on your target platform.

If you are looking at one algorithm vs. another one, you can look for data that others have already gathered and that will give you a rough idea.  For instance, here are some benchmarks from Crypto++:
http://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks.html

Note that they use MB/Second and Cycles/Byte as metrics.  I think those are very good choices.

Answer (score 3):

Some very good answers before me, but keep in mind optimizations are a very good way to leak key material by [timing attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack) (for example see [how devastating it can be for AES](http://cr.yp.to/antiforgery/cachetiming-20050414.pdf)). If there is any chance an attacker can time your operations you want not the fastest but the most constant time library available (and possibly the most constant power usage available, if there is any chance someone can monitor yours). OpenSSL does a great job of keeping on top of current attacks, can't necessarily say the same things of other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

My comments above aside, the US government has the [FIPS program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_140-2) that you might want to look at.  It's not perfect (by a long shot) but it's a start -- you can get an idea of things they were looking at when evaluation cryptography.

I also suggest looking at the [Computer Security Division of the NIST](http://csrc.nist.gov/).

Also, on a side note ... reviewing what the master has to say (Bruce Schneier) on the subject of [Security Pitfalls in Cryptography](http://www.schneier.com/essay-028.html) is always good.  Also:  [Security is harder than it looks](http://www.schneier.com/essay-037.html).